# Getting Error in extent reports for selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I am tyring to use the extent reports in my selenium framework. I have added maven dependency 2.41.2 in the POM file

I am getting error in this line

`OExtentReporter = new ExtentReports("C:\\testing.html",true);`

```
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 10, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 9, Time elapsed: 57.01 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
SetupSuite(com.XXXX.XXXX.AddNewCandidateTest)  Time elapsed: 36.903 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
```

I tried using the extent reports in a fresh project and everything worked fine. But whenever I am trying to create it in the actual framework, its throwing this error.

Also, as you can see that my results says that I executed 10 tests, but I have only one test in my testng.xml, which executes fine as soon as I remove extent report objects.

Please provide your suggestions and let me know, if you need any other details

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2011/08/classnotfoundexception-in-java-example.html

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy I understand the error, but I what I dont understand is why extent report library is throwing this error at initialization.

Answer (score 0):

As per the exception, Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal. So you need to have necessary library that has this class. 
*selenium-server-standalaone.jar   has that class.